# Split a string based on characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following string

```
Provider [DAVIS HOSPITAL AND MEDICAL CENTER,1231456] was not on file for Payer [HIMCD];  [AAA*Y**51*C; ];
```

I would like to split this string into 3 parts

```
Provider = Provider [DAVIS HOSPITAL AND MEDICAL CENTER,1231456] 
Payer = [HIMCD]
Error = [AAA*Y**51*C; ]
```

Can anyone suggest a simple sql query

```
DECLARE @second_char nvarchar(10)

SET @first_char = '[';
SET @second_char = ']';

SELECT @first_char,@second_char
DECLARE @message varchar(max)

DECLARE @firstindex int
DECLARE @secondindex int
DECLARE @thirdindex int
DECLARE @fourthindex int
SET @message = 'Provider[DAVIS HOSPITAL AND MEDICAL CENTER,12345678] was not on file for Payer [HIMCD];  [AAA*Y**51*C; ];'
SET @firstindex =  charINDEX(@first_char, @message,0)
SET @secondindex =  charINDEX(@second_char,@message,0)
SET @thirdindex =  charINDEX(@first_char, @message,@secondindex)
SET @fourthindex =  charINDEX(@second_char,@message,@thirdindex)
SElect @firstindex,@secondindex,@thirdindex,@fourthindex
```

This is what I had. The string is hardcoded here but usually its from a table. Any better ways would be appreciated

Comment: I used a substring based on substring(@stiring, 0, length). But this doesn't seem to be good

Comment: String manipulation isn't really standardized in SQL, you'll pretty much have to pick an RDBMS (MySQL/SQL Server/Oracle/...) to do this.

Comment: @user575219 The second parameter of substring is the one-based start index, not zero based. You need to be calling charindex to find the first square bracket, then again to find the first comma after it, etc. Once you have the offsets where everything you want begins and ends, you can call substring to get the substrings. If you read the documentation for substring and charindex, you'll be able to pass the correct parameters and get the results you want. There's no simple query. There is learning some trivial bits of SQL and thinking through the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is a temporary table and `CROSS APPLY`

```
DECLARE @T table
(
    string_data VARCHAR(MAX)
)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES ('Provider [DAVIS HOSPITAL AND MEDICAL CENTER,1231456] was not on file for Payer [HIMCD];  [AAA*Y**51*C; ]')

SELECT SUBSTRING(string_data,Idx1.pos,Idx1.pos2-Idx1.pos+1) as first_part,
       SUBSTRING(string_data,Idx2.pos,Idx2.pos2-Idx2.pos+1) AS second_part,
       SUBSTRING(string_data,Idx3.pos,Idx3.pos2-Idx3.pos+1) AS third_part
FROM @T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('[', string_data) AS pos, CHARINDEX(']', string_data) AS pos2) AS Idx1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('[', string_data, Idx1.pos2+1) AS pos, CHARINDEX(']', string_data, Idx1.pos2+1) AS pos2) AS Idx2
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('[', string_data, Idx2.pos2+1) AS pos, CHARINDEX(']', string_data, Idx2.pos2+1) AS pos2) AS Idx3
```

**EDIT**
Just saw that you said the data is from a table, in which case, you shouldn't need the temp table.